# An increasing number of

Tags: verbs

Is the following sentence incorrect?

> An increasing number of interconnected devices **create** more potential openings for hackers to exploit.

Or **creates** should be used in place of **create**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage is decided by the article (indefinite 'a' or 'an', definite 'the'). Although '**a** number' is strictly singular, 'a number of' is used as a determiner with plural nouns. The verb should therefore be plural - **a** number of animals **are** in the forest. Note that '**the** number' is singular - **the** number of people here **is** small.

> **An** increasing number of interconnected devices **create** more potential
> openings for hackers to exploit.
>
> **The** increasing number of interconnected devices **creates** more potential
> openings for hackers to exploit.

[Number of people is or are (Lexico)](https://www.lexico.com/explore/number-of-people-is-or-are)